# Python: improve the result of concat of 2 csv files

Tags: python, csv, concatenation

I want to concatenate two csv files file1.csv and file2.csv

file1.csv (first line):

```
6.365055485717639923e+10,6.365055501027899170e+10
```

file2.csv (first line):

```
153.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to have the following result:

```
6.365055485717639923e+10,6.365055501027899170e+10,153.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

When executing the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.read_csv('Baseline_X_reduced.csv', header=None, sep=',')
Y = pd.read_csv('Baseline_X_reduced2.csv', header=None, sep=',')
Z = pd.concat([Y, X], axis=1)
Z.to_csv('Baseline_X_revised.csv', header=None, sep=',', index=False)
```

I got the following result:

```
**63650554857.17639,63650555010.27899**,153.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I lost some informations for the two values in bold.

Is there a way to keep the same values from the file1.csv (6.365055485717639923e+10,6.365055501027899170e+10) with same format ?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Isn't this just a display issue? For instance what does `df.iloc[0].values[0]` show?

Comment: These values don't look like they'll fit in a `double` so you'll lose some precision. Was the source IEEE extended by any chance?

Comment: @EdChum I don't think not-getting 19 digits out of a double is a 'display issue'

Comment: @pvg my point is that the full value is actually there, it's just not displaying the full digits is my query

Comment: What version pandas are you using? I get `',6.365055485717639923e+10,6.365055501027899170e+10,153.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,5,1,0.6,4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.20,0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29,0.30\n'` as the output which seems correct

Comment: @EdChum no, it's not. The full value can't be represented by a `double`. These values just don't fit with that degree of precision.

Comment: @pvg well it works fine for me so there's something else wrong here

Comment: @EdChum can't argue with reproducible!

Comment: @pvg I take it back, what I saw was the header not the data, the data is being truncated so I'm investigating this

Comment: @EdChum yeah my guess is these are IEEE extendeds that op got from somewhere. Some if it just going to have to get tossed. Or treated as text, not doubles.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the values to be converted, do not convert them! pandas module is great at processing floating point values, but floating point values are known to have no exact representation.

But the csv module can process the value as text:

```
import csv

#open 2 input files and 1 output file
with open('Baseline_X_reduced.csv') as fd1, open('Baseline_X_reduced2.csv') as fd2:
    with open('Baseline_X_revised.csv', 'w') as fdout:
        # setup csv accessors for all files
        rd1 = csv.reader(fd1)
        rd2 = csv.reader(fd2)
        wr = csv.writer(fdout)
        while True:
            try:
                # combine lines...
                row1 = next(rd1)
                row2 = next(rd2)
                wr.writerow(row1 + row2)
            except StopIteration:
                # and stop once the shorter input file is exhausted
                break
```

This code will process the files line by line, so can be used even if the size of files is greater that the available memory

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i tested the previous solution and it works :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Pandas so I cannot help with Pandas' related issues. However, if you want to approach this from a text-processing issue, here is a straight-forward solution:

```
with open('file1.csv') as input1, \
        open('file2.csv') as input2, \
        open('Baseline_X_revised.csv', 'w') as output:

    for line1, line2 in zip(input1, input2):
        line1 = line1.rstrip()
        line2 = line2.rstrip()
        output.write('{},{}\n'.format(line1, line2))
```

**Notes**

- One problem with this solution is it stripping off any trailing spaces or tabs
- The solution assumes the two files are of the same number of lines